# How can I make my condition check case-insensitive?

Tags: python

My first Python program gets an input from the user about his birthday and calculate if he or she is 18+.

My while loop won't continue if the string "check" is equal to `true`; it's only working for `True`. Why not?

```
import time
import datetime

check = "Null"
year_born = month_born = day_born = 0

while check != "True":
#or check!="true":
        year_born = input("what year were you born?")
        month_born = input("what month were you born?")
        day_born = input("what day were you born?")
        check = raw_input("your birth day is on {0}/{1}/{2}... type 'True' to confirme: ".format(day_born, month_born, year_born))

year_now = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y"))
month_now = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%m"))
day_now = int(datetime.date.today().strftime("%d"))

if (year_now - 18 > year_born) or (year_now - 18 == year_born and month_born <= month_now and day_born <= day_now):
        print("You are 18+. you are allowed to enter")

else: 
        print("Good bye")
```

I tried `while check != "True" or "true"` and `while check != "True" or check != "true"` and `while ((check != "True") or (check != "true))`. None of them seem to work; it's just ignoring "true" and "True" and keeps looping.

Comment: Why do you have the second part of the condition on the next line in a comment?

Comment: `while check.lower()!='true':`

Comment: `check = None` instead of `check="Null"`

Comment: Input returns a string, so `year_born` etc are not numbers. You have to convert them with `int()` into an integer to perform a subtraction.

Comment: Moment of clarity: why are you storing a bool as a string? You could simplify it a lot by having `check = False ` and then `while check:`

Answer (score 1):

Try normalizing the input by using [.lower()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower).

```
>>> 'True'.lower() == 'true'
True
>>> 'true'.lower() == 'true'
True
>>> 'TRUE'.lower() == 'true'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You did something weird with the while conditional. Try `while check not in ["true","True"]:`